# Mouse hover is working on dreamweaver real-time preview but not on my hosted website

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, bluehost

I am using Dreamweaver to develop a website. I am trying to use CSS to get the following effect. SO basically when I hover my mouse over the image, I want the image to go dark and show me some text.[image]

This works fine on Dreamweaver realtime-preview but not on my hosted website. On my hosted website, it shows this:
[image]

Mt HTML code is:

```css
.col {
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: "#EAEAEA";
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: 5%;
 margin-top: 5%;
 position: relative;
}

.col:hover .responsive-image {
 transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
 transform: scale(1.2);
 filter: brightness(20%);
}

.responsive-image {
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 100%;
 height: 250px;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 overflow: hidden;
 max-width: 100%;
 transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}


.text-on-image {
 opacity: 0;
 transition: .5s ease;
}


.col:hover .text-on-image {
 opacity: 1;
 transition: .5s ease;
}

.text-heading {
 color: white;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: 100;
 letter-spacing: 0.1em;
 position: absolute;
 top: 35%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
}

.text-desc {
 color: white;
 font-weight: 200;
 letter-spacing: 0.1em;
 font-size: 15px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 70%;
 left: 50%;
 width: 100%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="col col-lg">
   <img class="responsive-image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Yelish"/>
   <div class="text-on-image">
    <div class="text-heading">
     Yelish
    </div>
    <div class="text-desc">
     A social networking iOS app where people can find the most happening places around them or in any city in the world
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you share link to your hosted site ?

Comment: http://vishishttiwari.com/

Comment: if you see, your css on hosted site dont have `.col:hover .responsive-image` declaration, kindly check if your latest changes have been uploaded correctly

Comment: Due to some very strange reason, dreamweaver is not hosting these classes on styles. Would you know why?

Comment: no idea about workings of dreamweaver